# How to fit three photos col-4 each beneath one image with a col-12?

Tags: css, grid, bootstrap-5, image-gallery

I'm having trouble with the bootstrap 5 grid. Basically, I want to have one full image with a col-12 and 600px to take a max width of 100% and to place three images, each 200px with a col-4, so I get one image on top and three beneath it with g-3 for spacing between the three images. So I created two seperated rows under one container with img-fluid for each image so the image takes the full width but the problem is that the 3 images are not fitting the right way please have a look
[image: 3 images]

also this is my code that i am writing

```
 <div class="container text-center pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid pb-2" src="./images/01.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/04.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and that's the end outcome I'm looking for.
[image]

I did get back to bootstrap 5 documentation and did copy and past same structure but i am still getting the same result please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the container-fluid for container

```html
 <div class="container-fluid text-center pt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"><img class="img-fluid pb-2" src="./images/01.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img class="img-fluid " src="./images/04.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nah i still got the same result !!!

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, I needed to provide the container size, so I added a class called container-box and gave it a width of 600 px, resulting in the following code.

```
<div class="container container-box text-center pt-5">
  <style>.container-box{
    width: 600px;
 }</style>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12"><img width="600" class="img-fluid pb-2" src="./images/01.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row g-3">
    <div class="col-4"><img width="200" class="img-fluid " src="./images/02.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img width="200" class="img-fluid " src="./images/03.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="col-4"><img width="200" class="img-fluid " src="./images/04.jpg" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```